# How can I know the compatibility of Java and jTDS?

Tags: java-8, jtds

I have Java 8 update 101 and I'm using the jTDS 1.2.5

I received the following error:

> org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: There is an error in get connection, I/O Error: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property.

So I've a question: How can I know the compatibility of Java and jTDS?

I've checked on their site: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/ 
But I cannot find the java compatibility in the release note. The 1.2.5 jTDS works with java 7 but not 8 and it's written JDBC 3 in the release note

I may do not understand the error too.

Comment: For Java 8 you need to use jTDS 1.3.x if I'm not mistaken. But the error "*Native SSPI library not loaded*" has nothing to do with the Java version. You are trying to use Windows authentication but the required `ntlmauth.dll` can't be loaded by your application

Comment: In general it seems the project isn't really active. It's probably better to use the Microsoft JDBC driver anyway: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/mt683464.aspx in my experience the 4.x version is really good at seems to work better then the somewhat outdated jTDS

Comment: Oh yes that's exactly the file `ntlmauth.dll`. I've checked and this file is not missing. How can I load this file, because yes, I'm using Windows authentication?

Comment: Maybe there is a mismatch between 64bit and 32bit? It depends on your application on how it loads the jTDS driver. But in general you should add the directory containing the dll to `java.library.path` just as the exception says

Comment: Like? I'm using a 32 bit for Java and I'm on a windows 64 Bit or my application is install on 64 bit?  - Thanks for the post reviewing

Comment: Thanks I understand! Thanks a lot for your help, it was very helpful

Comment: Hi again @a_horse_with_no_name, Basic question again. I use a ntlmauth.dll 32 Bit and a 64 bit JVM. Is it my problem? That should works?  - Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a 32 bit for Java and my application was install on 64 bit. That cannot work !

Thanks for your help @a_horse_with_no_name